# How can I convert this string to date?

Tags: c#, .net, string, datetime

Im making a post from a view and getting it in a actionresult as a string. 
The value I get is:

> Tue Feb 18 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil)

Using `DateTime.Parse` throws an exception:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

What makes this string invalid, and how can I successfully convert it to a `DateTime`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) throws exception for this string because it does not have a *standart date/time format.*

If your `GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil)` is *stable* in your string, you can use;

```
var s = "Tue Feb 18 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil)";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(s,
                              "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'K '(Hora oficial do Brasil)'",
                              CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(date);
```

Output will be;

```
2/18/2014 12:00:00 AM
```

Here is a [demonstration](http://ideone.com/yuMK0f).

I don't think there is a way to parse your `(Hora oficial do Brasil)` part except using string delimiter.

Take a look at;

- [`The "K" Custom Format Specifier`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#KSpecifier)

I don't know why `K` specifier doesn't work on Ideone actually. I have to put `-0300` part also as a string delimiter for generating example. It can be an issue with [`DateTimeKind` enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shx7s921%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but I'm not sure..

Comment: Yes, the problem that im getting this date of a devexpress controller and this controller dont let me format the date.

Comment: And if the GMT-0300 (Hora oficial do Brasil) is not stable? What do you suggest?

Comment: @ggui Unfortunately, if your string isn't stable, this might not be a solution. There is a limited custom string formats, take a look from MSDN [`Custom Date and Time Format Strings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The string is invalid because of the `'GMT'` and the `'(Hora oficial do Brasil)'` parts. 
Simply put: the parser is unable to determine what is part of a date time and what is not.

By using format strings you will be able to parse the string into the DateTime format.

see: [MSDN: Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

in your case this format string will work: `"ddd MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss 'GMT'K '(Hora oficial do Brasil)'"`.

You can use it like this:

```
string input = "Tue Feb 18 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Hora official do Brasil)";
string[] format = { "ddd MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss 'GMT'K '(Hora official do Brasil)'" };

DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(input, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
    {
        //Yepee the input was parsed correct
    }
    else
    {
        //system was unable to parse the string
    }
```

Or like this if error handling is not nessesary:

```
string input = "Tue Feb 18 2014 00:00:00 GMT-0300 (Hora official do Brasil)";
string format = "ddd MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss 'GMT'K '(Hora official do Brasil)'";

DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(input, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```